# Create Language Localization for View Models C#

Tags: c#, localization, cross-platform, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a localization system to handle different languages within our application. I have a Common Module where all the magic should happen, which the View Models access to get the correct string value based on the Language.

The applications language e.g. `"en_US"` is passed to the Common Modules `LocaleLanguage` class, which should then return the required object containing all the strings relevant to that language. E.g:

```
public object GetLanguageClass()
{
    switch (language)
    {
        case "en_US":
            return new en_US();
        ....
        default:
            return new en_US();
    }
}
```

Each `en_US` etc class just has public strings within them. I attempted to use Xml files, but this hasn't worked.

The **problem** is that the returned `object` is an object, which prevents me from accessing the classes public strings. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ResourceManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class and [satellite assemblies](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/global_developer/2011/07/22/introduction-to-satellite-assemblies/) for localization. That way, you will not need to create individual classes for each language.

When you set the [`DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture(v=vs.110).aspx), the `ResourceManager` will look the resources up in the corresponding folder.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

The resource file needs to be in the "en-US" folder in this case.

You can then call the [`GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `ResourceManager` to get your localized string.

```
Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager("Resources", executingAssembly);
string localizedString = resourceManager.GetString("resourceKey");
```

To create the satellite assemblies (`.resources.dll` files) from `resx` files, you need to use [`resgen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccec7sz1(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`al`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex(v=vs.110).aspx). `resgen` creates the `.resources` file and `al` generates `dll` from that.

Comment: Brilliant thanks!! Will give it a try, definitely a good solution. I just found a solution as well - posting it.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to return a `Dictionary<string, string>` from the class instead of the class containing string fields. The language classes e.g. `en_US` will each have a list which the classes adds too. E.g: `en_US`:

```
 LanguageUS.Add("name", "Test US Name");
```

Then the `GetLanguageClass` returns a dictionary:

```
case "en_US":
     return new en_US().LanguageUS;
```

A key can then be used to get the value as required.